# Do I need an Ubuntu certification to teach Ubuntu

Tags: certificates, certification

I have several students that want a course of Ubuntu. I would like to know the following very important points:

1. Do I need an Ubuntu certification to certified my students afterwards that they know Ubuntu.
2. Can I use the Ubuntu logo, an Ubuntu symbol for the certificate that I would give out?
   Do I need permissions?
   Where should I ask for permission?
   Is this possible?
3. Is there an Ubuntu certificate format available that I could use?
4. Is there a site where I could sign to teach and promote Ubuntu to new users (Become an Ubuntu teacher)?
5. What information and permissions might I need from Ubuntu or Canonical if I wanted to give courses about Ubuntu?

Comment: What sort of education? in what form? And where?

Comment: You have 11.9K rep on Ask Ubuntu. If that isn't enough of a certification, then I don't know what is. (over generalizing, but it's overall true)

Comment: #2's an easy one: Contact Canonical and ask them.  #1, #3, #4: I'm not sure handing out "Ubuntu" certificates is a good idea, since there's no true Ubuntu certifications available.

Comment: @LordofTime - How do I contact canonical for this specific question. Is it the same email for everything or is there an specific for this sort of things?

Comment: I'm not sure of the email.  I do know the Ubuntu and related imagery is all copyrighted by them.  I'll ask around, get you an answer to #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 . No

2.Yes you can use. But you should obtain permission from canonical

3.AFAIK no

4.I don't know about such sites, But you are already doing it here(askubuntu.com)

5.There is no need of permissions to teach ubuntu

Comment: sorry for the late accept. I was wondering if you could also add the link to the site where one could ask Canonical for permission to use their Logo and anything else on a Self made certificate. Something that shows that the participant was on that course and he/she learned Ubuntu.

Comment: You can't represent / provide "Ubuntu certification", the use of teh trademark has several restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

Anyone can teach about Ubuntu and a certification is not required.

Manuals for 11.10 can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/). Particularly the [Ubuntu desktop help](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/index.html) will be useful to you if you want to cover the desktop (the other 2 are about server and installing).

Comment: I appreciate your input and jrg. It is just that in my country you can be Linus Torvalds but if you do not have a certificate that says you know Linux then it does not count.

Comment: I know ppl with LPI certificates that I would not trust setting up security...

Comment: Hi buddy, I updated the question since I wanted to make sure of some points and was pondering over for months.

Comment: Linux+ (LPI) is a good "LInux" certification, but its not a security certification, rinzwind.  CISSP certs are good for security ;P

Comment: Not, not anyone can use the Ubuntu trademark. There are several restrictions.

Comment: @MagicFab my answer was made before the edit ;) There was no such thing as a bullet point 2 when I answered this otherwise I would have pointed to http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy. Thanks for the downvote on something the topic started added AFTER I answered.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that if there's a commercial intent to your use, then you will
>   always need a formal license from us for trademarks and copyright
>   materials. Commercial use may not be compatible with Ubuntu project
>   values; in particular, the inter-play of trust and generosity that
>   lies at the heart of open source, so we have a special need to
>   evaluate any commercial usage of the Trademarks.

From: http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy

On that page several parts explain general restrictions on the use of the Ubuntu trademark and indicate you must obtain a license, by contacting Canonical first:
https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/

Unfortunately Canonical terminated their certification programs some time ago, so getting a certification to at least validate your knowledge in some formal/official  capacity isn't possible anymore. LPIC certifications are your next best thing.